# Regex - Extract path from url without last /

Tags: regex, url, path

I have following regex expression

```
(.*[\/])
```

This will match 
    /path/tooo/url/

from this string

```
/path/tooo/url/blablabla-xxxxx
```

My question is how to modify regex to match

```
/path/tooo/url
```

(without last /)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach. Match each instance of a forward-slash followed by one or more characters that are not a forward-slash, then match one or more instances of that. Keep matching until we find an instance of a forward-slash followed by only non-forward-slash characters (negative lookahead).

```
((?:\/[^\/]+)+)(?=\/[^\/]+)
```

I put a capturing group around the whole thing because it appears you want to capture the result in a capturing group (your regex is wrapped in parens).

I'm using a non-capturing group for the inner regex: (?:) because we don't need to capture this group. See: [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group)

Comment: This matches the whole string /path/tooo/url/blablabla-xxxxx

Comment: Oh sorry, I totally misread your question. Let me adjust my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you.